# Inserting Option via AJAX using Settings API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am making a plugin and need to insert a value using the '[add_option()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/)' function - or something that achieves the same result.

This is what I use to call my AJAX:

```
// localize script
wp_localize_script('button-js', 'the_ajax_script', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

And what launches the PHP function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_process_form', array($this, 'process_ajax'));
```

I need to run add_option() in the function called *after* my AJAX runs (my AJAX code below):

```
function post(num) {

    var data = {
        action : 'process_form',
        form_number : num   
    };

    $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data).error(
        function() {
            alert('error');
        }).success(function() {
            console.log(data);
        });

        return false;
}
```

And here is the function that is run by AJAX:

```
public function process_ajax() {
    $num = $_POST['form_number'];

    if(isset($num)) {
        add_option('form-num', $num); 
    }

    die();

}
```

My AJAX code runs successfully, and the correct values are logged to the console - however upon using

```
<?php echo get_option('form_num'); ?>
```

The value is blank.

Comment: This is Wordpress, I posted into the wrong community... dangit.

Comment: Is it a typo that the add_option uses 'form-num' and you are outputting the option 'form_num'? If not, that might be the cause.